# MSSQL - how to select words on alphabetic order from one string

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I have the following string in database: `'test data'`, but I need to select it the way that output would be in alphabetic order like this: `'data test'`

Comment: Essentially you are storing delimited data in a single column (where your delimiter is a space). This is bad practice. That being said, if you share with us which RDBMS you are using (sql server, postgres, oracle, etc) there may be a way to split a delimited string into its own record, sort, and then string-agg them back together in your alphabetical order.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Looks like SQL Server. Which version? 2016 or newer have `STRING_SPLIT()` which will split delimited data into rows. With a `CROSS APPLY` to your original table you can preserve the keys for each outputted word. Sticking them back together is a bit more work, unless you have version 2017 or newer where `STRING_AGG` is added.

Comment: This is a valid question. i dont know why it is being marked down?

Comment: 1. OP has enough points to understand the importance of tagging. 2. seems like http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @jonway 3. It shows little research effort. 1(again).The original question before it was edited was just tagged `sql`. 4. The question shows no attempt to solve or share what they've tried already. 5. The question originally had misspelled words. (Not a biggie, since we could probably all understand what was meant by "Alphapedic"). That being said, I didn't downvote, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @JNevill, Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I do agree that this feels like an XY problem though. Delimited data should be stored with each term as its own record in a separate table, making this a cakewalk. Either that or it's a homework question written by a sadist.

Comment: Or it is a developer trying to work with a database designed by someone who should work somewhere else - prefeably McDonalds. In 30 years of IT I have seen this way too often - and there is no way around "this is the database that our appslications use", no way to refactor that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments. I managed to figure out something what will do the trick for me. If anyone else is looking something similar, then I used the following approach:

```
select abc=STUFF((
select ' ' + b.n 
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by n asc) as rn, n 
    from (
        select RIGHT('test data', LEN('test data') - CHARINDEX(' ', 'test data')) as n
        union all
        select LEFT('test data',  CHARINDEX(' ', 'test data')) as f
        ) a
     ) b order by rn asc
for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```